# How can I refresh a part of a page using react js?

Tags: reactjs

So I want to know how does online exam websites work.
Where a file is used to showcase the questions and only a part of the page get refreshed.

Thanks!!
Forgive for many mistake my first time in here.

Comment: You might want to read about [Reacts Virtual DOM](https://programmingwithmosh.com/react/react-virtual-dom-explained/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's how React.js works actually. React uses virtual DOM instead of using directly DOM. In basic terms, Virtual DOM is copy of the real DOM and updates changes inside then compares difference between real DOM and virtual DOM to update the part that has changed in DOM. You can find deeper informations if you check on web, I would recommend you to check Virtual DOM and Binary search tree.